# Filtrar por fechas en Visula Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

Buen día.

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy tratando de hacer que se llene el DataGridView mediante una colsuta de SQL, pero no funciona
Pongo el codigo que llena el DataGridView:

```
     Sub Consulta(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal FI As DateTimePicker, 
     ByVal FF As DateTimePicker)
       Try
            adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter("select dt. 
                                            SerialNumber,dt.Modelo,dt.Date, 
                                            dt.TestUser, dt. 
                                            [Comments/Actions] TestComments, 
                                            d.DebugUser, d.DebugComments
                                        from Debug d left join
                                        Debug_Test dt on
                                        dt.SerialNumber=d.SerialNumber
                                        where dt.Date between '" & FF.Value 
                                       & "' and '" & FI.Value & "'", cn)
        dt = New DataTable
        adaptador.Fill(dt)
        dgv.DataSource = dt
        dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns(1), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error al llenar la Grilla: " + ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
       --asi llamo la funcion de llenar el DataGridView
      Private Sub RegistroPruebas_Diagnostico_Load(sender As Object, e As 
 EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    obj.Consulta(Reporte_TestDebug, FechaInicial, FechaFinal)
End Sub
```

La ventana es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Comment: en tu metodo consulta solo usa date no hace falta datetimepicker

Comment: @Manny me puedes dar un ejemplo por favor.

Comment: FI = Fecha Inicial, y FF = Fecha Final ?? Si es así el orden del `between` esta al revés.

Comment: A parte del comentario de @ljcordero que es correcto, debe saber cual es el formato que contiene `dt.Date` para saber en que formato debe colocar  `FI.Value` y `FF.Value`, ya sea `yyyy/MM/dd` o `dd/MM/yyyy` entre otros formatos..

Comment: @ljcordero gracias

Comment: @J.Rodríguez El formato de la fecha es MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 2):

La solucion a ese problema fue cambiar el orden en la sentencia de SQL del between.

```
Sub Consulta(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal FI As DateTimePicker, ByVal FF As DateTimePicker)
    Try
        adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter("select dt. SerialNumber,dt.Modelo,dt.Date, dt.TestUser, dt.[Comments/Actions] TestComments, d.DebugUser, d.DebugComments
                                        from Debug d left join
                                        Debug_Test dt on dt.SerialNumber =d.SerialNumber
                                        where dt.Date between '" & FI.Value & "' and '" & FF.Value & "'", cn)
        dt = New DataTable
        adaptador.Fill(dt)
        dgv.DataSource = dt
        dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns(1), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error al llenar la Grilla: " + ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Giovanni, la seccion de respuestas no esta para hacer preguntas nuevas. Si crees que esta pregunta es diferente no dudes en crear una **nueva** pregunta

Comment: @Capt.Teach Gracias

Comment: Esto no es una solucion, solo demuestra que el error era basicamente dos parametros al reves...